# EF Core query where Were clause is a collection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I am trying to build a sane query in EF Core that returns a collection of things that are, in turn derived from a collection of things. Basically in raw SQL one would do a JOIN.

Its in ASP.NET Core so the initial collection is the list of Roles on the `SecurityPrincipal` object:

```
var roles = User.FindAll(ClaimTypes.Role).Select(r=>r.Value);
```

These roles are then mapped to Groups in our Database, so I can look those up:

```
var groupsQuery = dbContext.Groups.Where(g=>roles.Any(r=>r==g.GroupName));
var groups = await groupsQuery.ToListAsync();
```

This query is quite happy and returns a collection of groups as expected. The groups however have access to another resource, which is what I really want and because its a many to many relationship there is a bridging table.

This is me trying to query the AssetGroup joining table so I can get all the Assets referenced by all the Groups that map to a Role on the `SecurityPrincipal`.

```
var assetGroupsQuery = dbContext.AssetsGroups.Where(ag => groupsQuery.Any(ag => ag.Id == a.GroupId));
var assetGroups = await assetGroupsQuery.ToListAsync();
```

When I perform the second query I get a lot of spam in my output window:

```
  The LINQ expression 'where ([ag].Id == [ag].GroupId)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
  The LINQ expression 'Any()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
  The LINQ expression 'where {from Group g in __groups_0 where ([ag].Id == [ag].GroupId) select [ag] => Any()}' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
  The LINQ expression 'where ([ag].Id == [ag].GroupId)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
  The LINQ expression 'Any()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
```

Any clues on how one should phrase a nested query like this so EF Core can compose a single SQL query properly?

Comment: Can you provide database structure with this tables?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In general avoid using `Any` or any LINQ operator other than `Contains` on *in memory collection* like your `roles` (which according to the code should be of type `IEnumerable<string>`).

In other words, instead of

```
.Where(g => roles.Any(r => r == g.GroupName))
```

use the functionally equivalent

```
.Where(g => roles.Contains(g.GroupName))
```

The later is guaranteed to be translated to SQL `IN`, while the former isn't.

Interestingly and at the same time misleading is that EF Core tries to be smart and translate the former the same way as `Contains`, and succeeds when the containing query is executed, but not when used as part of another query.

It could be considered a current EF Core implementation defect. But the workaround/solution is (as mentioned in the beginning) to not rely on it and always use `Contains`.

Comment: `In general avoid using Any`. What about this `_dbContext.Users.Any(u => u.Email == email)` will this is not guaranteed to be translated to SQL?

Comment: @TanvirArjel "..on in memory collection"

Comment: First it will load all the users into memory then perfrom checking on memory?

Comment: @TanvirArjel I meant, the case is different. Yours is **not** in-memory collection, but real `IQueryable<>`, so no problem of using `Any`.